# Sharepoint annoyances: What is name.dll?

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, activex

When I log into our intranet (using IE, unfortunately), each page has a warning that it wants to run the following add-on: "name.dll" from "Microsoft Corporation".

How can I make this warning go away permanently, without installing the ActiveX DLL?

Answer (score 5):

This error is caused by the functionality shows a presence icon against people's names. The downside of adding the site to the Trusted Sites list is that it reduces security but is the only option that retains this functionality (unless you can devise the correct custom IE security settings).

**If you don't need the presence icon:**

Method 2 from the Microsoft article means that patches they make to the Init.js file will never make it into your InitNoPresence.js file. The way they describe commenting out the .js file also results in JavaScript errors.

A nicer alternative IMHO is to add empty ProcessImn and ProcessImnMarkers functions that override the existing to the master page:

```
function ProcessImn()
{ }
function ProcessImnMarkers()
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN :

**Add the SharePoint site to the Trusted Sites list in Internet Explorer 7 on the Windows client computer**

Add the SharePoint site to the Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer 7 on the Microsoft Windows client computer. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Start Internet Explorer 7.
2. On the Tools menu, click Internet
   Options, and then click the Security
   tab.
3. Click Trusted sites, and then click
   Sites.
4. In the Trusted sites dialog box,
   type the URL of the SharePoint site
   in the Add this website to the zone
   box, and then click Add.
5. Click Close, and then click OK.

Comment: +1 for clarity and usefulness of answer, but -1 for suggesting that a Google Search by the OP would have been, um, better?  Shinier?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it requires that I download and run the dll - I want a way to NOT do that, and NOT get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931509) describing this problem and how to resolve it from both the client and server side.

Comment: Except their Method 2 causes JavaScript errors and sucks from a deployment perspective. Have answered with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the name.dll generates a little menu when you hover over a user's name in sharepoint that allows you to see if and where he is available and allows for the scheduling of meetings and such. Presence info is only available when you have Office Communications Server running in your domain.